# OSGi Fragment connection to a bundle

Tags: internationalization, osgi, fragment

I want to create a Fragment which will connect to a bundle living in an OSGi container.
I cannot find any documentation about the content of each Manifest.MF files for both sides (Fragment and Bundle).
Can anyone give me a good example in order to fully understand it.
A source code example it will be the best.

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

If the host bundle has the following in its manifest:

```
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.example.myhostbundle
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
```

then the fragment should have:

```
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.example.myfragment
Fragment-Host: org.example.myhostbundle; bundle-version="[1.0,1.1)"
```

Please see the [OSGi wiki page](http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Fragment) for more detailed information.